# Docker Desktop for windows - Waiting for SSH to be available... getting IPV6 address

Tags: ssh, ipv6, ipv4, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop, docker

**Expected behavior**

Docker is up and running!

**Actual behavior**

Waiting for SSH to be available...

**Steps to reproduce the behavior**

`docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "myswitch" myvm1` (from https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#set-up-your-swarm)

Hi All, I'm getting "waiting for SSH to be available" when I try to create a docker machine with hyperV driver but sometimes it's working and sometimes not so I got the following logs. The only thing that changes is the version of the IP address : the creation fail with an IPV6. The instruction "networkadapters[0]).ipaddresses[0]" got IPV6 address when the machine creation is failing.

**When the machine is created with no errors :**

```
Waiting for SSH to be available...
(myvm1) DBG | [stderr =====>] :
Getting to WaitForSSH function...
(myvm1) Calling .GetSSHHostname
(myvm1) DBG | [executing ==>] : C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive ( Get-VM myvm1 ).state
(myvm1) DBG | [stdout =====>] : Running
(myvm1) DBG |
(myvm1) DBG | [stderr =====>] :
(myvm1) DBG | [executing ==>] : C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive (( Get-VM myvm1 ).networkadapters[0]).ipaddresses0 DBG | [stdout =====>] : 10.23.133.214
(myvm1) DBG |
(myvm1) DBG | [stderr =====>] :
(myvm1) Calling .GetSSHPort
(myvm1) Calling .GetSSHKeyPath
(myvm1) Calling .GetSSHKeyPath
(myvm1) Calling .GetSSHUsername
Using SSH client type: external
&{[-F /dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none docker@10.23.133.214 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i C:\Users\Toto.docker\machine\machines\myvm1\id_rsa -p 22] C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe }
About to run SSH command:
exit 0
SSH cmd err, output: :
Detecting the provisioner...
```

**When the machine is created with error :**

```
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Getting to WaitForSSH function...
(myvm2) Calling .GetSSHHostname
(myvm2) DBG | [executing ==>] : C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive ( Get-VM myvm2 ).state
(myvm2) DBG | [stdout =====>] : Running
(myvm2) DBG |
(myvm2) DBG | [stderr =====>] :
(myvm2) DBG | [executing ==>] : C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive (( Get-VM myvm2 ).networkadapters[0]).ipaddresses0 DBG | [stdout =====>] : fe80::215:5dff:fe84:ac46
(myvm2) DBG |
(myvm2) DBG | [stderr =====>] :
(myvm2) Calling .GetSSHPort
(myvm2) Calling .GetSSHKeyPath
(myvm2) Calling .GetSSHKeyPath
(myvm2) Calling .GetSSHUsername
Using SSH client type: external
&{[-F /dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none docker@fe80::215:5dff:fe84:ac46 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i C:\Users\Toto.docker\machine\machines\myvm2\id_rsa -p 22] C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe }
About to run SSH command:
exit 0
SSH cmd err, output: exit status 255:
Error getting ssh command 'exit 0' : ssh command error:
command : exit 0
err : exit status 255
output :
Getting to WaitForSSH function...
```

**Information**

Diagnostic ID : 64F0C90F-2963-4B91-97A4-4E8B649571E2/2017-06-14_14-40-28

Version 17.03.1-ce-win12 (12058) Channel: stable d1db126

Windows 10 Entreprise

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I'm running the same command from the same *getting - started* tutorial, on Windows 10 with hyperV and it is **extremely** unstable, especially with SSH

Comment: That sounds funny, but a restart of `MobyLinuxVM`, `myvm1` and `myvm2` solved the issue.